# Why is my Sent folder empty in Outlook on Windows Mobile?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, windows-mobile

I'm using Outlook on Windows Mobile 6.1 connected to an Exchange server. Even if I check the Sent folder in my synchronization options, the folder always shows up as having no messages. Even emails that I've sent FROM my phone do not show up, leaving me with no way to view those. Anything else I can check or enable to see these messages?

Comment: Do you have "Save copies of messages in Sent Items folder" ticked in E-mail Options?

Comment: Yep, "Save copied of messages in Sent Items folder" is checked. But I can see neither messages sent from Windows Mobile or from my desktop Outlook in the Sent folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is not to synchronize the sent items folder.

Comment: That's what I had gathered - so my question really is, how do you enable it? Like I said, I've checked the box next to Sent Items under Manage Folders with no results. Nothing I send from Outlook Mobile shows up in there, and nothing I send from my desktop Outlook shows up in there through Exchange. Thanks.

Comment: when connected, but not while a synchronization is in progress, right click on "messages" in ActiveSync, click on the button that says "Folders", and choose "Sent Items".

I think this is right; I'm working from memory here.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in outlook 2007

Click on View - Current view - Select messages.

That should resolve the issue

that way you have all your messages in sent items folder in view.

Comment: Outlook on Windows Mobile 6.1... gravedigger!